# Have special chars and html tags in vue how to remove

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

solved with vue-html-secure, thanks all

from api I have this -

```
specs: &lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt; &lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Диагональ - 19&quot; &lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Интерфейсы - DVI, VGA&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;
```

use with

```
<div v-html="PRODUCT.specs"></div>
```

have this:

```
<table><tr><td> </td></tr><tr><td>Диагональ - 19" </td></tr><tr><td><td>Интерфейсы - DVI, VGA</td></tr></table>
```

how to remove html tags? or how to remove special chars at first?
trying to use sanitize have same

Comment: whats the expected output?

Comment: this: <table><tr><td> </td></tr><tr><td>Диагональ - 19" </td></tr><tr><td><td>Интерфейсы - DVI, VGA</td></tr></table>

to:
Диагональ - 19" 
Интерфейсы - DVI, VGA

Answer (score 1):

Use this library to sanitize it

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sanitize

then add a computed

```
checkHtml() {return this.$sanitize(my_api_value_with_html_tags)},
```

then on template

```
<div v-html="checkHtml"></div>
```

For any usage of v-html is good to take a look the official vue security page for v-html
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/security.html

Register plugin in main.js

```
let defaults = VueSanitize.defaults;
Vue.use(VueSanitize,defaults);
```

Comment: `checkHtml() {
      return this.$sanitize(this.PRODUCT.specs)
    },
`
with sanitize have same: 
`<table><tr><td> </td></tr><tr><td>Диагональ - 19" </td></tr><tr><td><td>Интерфейсы - DVI, VGA</td></tr></table>`

Comment: Did you register the plugin in main.js?


let defaults = VueSanitize.defaults;
Vue.use(VueSanitize,defaults);

Comment: im using nuxt:
`import Vue from 'vue';
import VueSanitize from "vue-sanitize";
Vue.use(VueSanitize);`
testing:
`
data() {
    return {
      test: `<table><tr><td> </td></tr><tr><td>Диагональ - 19" </td></tr><tr><td><td>Интерфейсы - DVI, VGA</td></tr></table>`
    }
  },
computed: {
checkHtml() {
      return this.$sanitize(this.test)
},} `
and that works good, 
and this not works `checkHtml() {return this.$sanitize(this.PRODUCT.specs)},`